# Content doesn't get scrolled in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native and stuck in styling problems.

[image]

As you can see in the pic, the content doesn't get scrolled if it's too much.

```
   <SafeAreaView style={Styles.body}>
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
        <IOSModal isOpen={isModalOpen} onClose={closeModal}>
          {dateTimePicker}
        </IOSModal>

        {isAndroidPickerOpen ? dateTimePicker : null}

        <View style={Styles.header}>
          <Text style={Styles.headerTitle}>Register Now</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={Styles.content}>
          <ValidatableForm onSave={onFormSave}>
            <ValidatableInput required validatable name="name" label="Name" />
            <ValidatableInput required validatable name="email" alias="email address" label="Email" />
            <ValidatableInput required validatable name="address" alias="address" label="Address" />
            <ValidatableInput required validatable name="name" label="Name" />
            <ValidatableInput required validatable name="email" alias="email address" label="Email" />
            <ValidatableInput required validatable name="address" alias="address" label="Address" />
            <ValidatableInput
              required
              validatable
              keyboardType="numeric"
              name="phone"
              alias="phone number"
              label="Phone"
            />
            <ValidatableDate
              name="dateOfBirth"
              label="Date of Birth"
              displayValue={displayValue}
              openDatePicker={openDatePicker}
            />
            <ValidatableInput required validatable name="password" label="Password" secureTextEntry />
            <ValidatableInput
              required
              validatable
              name="confirmPassword"
              alias="password confirmation"
              label="Confirm Password"
              secureTextEntry
            />
          </ValidatableForm>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
```

And these are the styles

```
    export const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
  body: {
    flex: 1,
    // height: variables.screenHeight,
    // backgroundColor: colors.blueDark,
  },

  header: {
    height: 100,
    ...padding(variables.halfPadding, variables.padding),
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    // backgroundColor: colors.red,
  },

  headerTitle: {
    fontSize: variables.fontSizeBigger,
    color: colors.white,
  },

  content: {
    flex: 1,
    ...padding(variables.halfPadding, variables.padding),
    borderTopRightRadius: variables.borderRadius * 5,
    borderTopLeftRadius: variables.borderRadius * 5,
    backgroundColor: colors.greyLight,
  },

  submitButtonWrapper: {
    ...padding(0),
  },
});
```

I am trying to implement both SafeAreaView ( for IOS 11+ ) and KeyboardAwareScrollView at the same time. I want my form to behave this way - If content (form) is too long, just add scrollbars, if not make the form content ( only the gray part ) grow all over the screen that I can make my submit button to be at the bottom of the screen .

**UPDATED**

If I remove `flex: 1` from *KeyboardAwareScrollView* , the scroll works, and everything works well apart from this situation , when the form fields are just a few.
See here, It needs the parent element to have a maximum height of the screen in order to stretch.
[image]

Comment: have a look at https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview

Comment: I know, KeyboardAwareScrollView uses it under the hood.

Comment: remove `flex:1` from `contentContainerStyle`, it should fix the problem.

Comment: Please, see updated version.

Comment: From your updated version, add a `flexGrow: 1` to the scrollview's `contentContainerView`.

Comment: can you update your question with dependency also I will run and give you working code

Comment: @Moistbobo Why does it work and flex: 1 didn't work?

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan because scrollviews work by essentially rendering its children offscreen; in other words its height has to exceed that of the screen for the content to be scrollable. By setting `flex: 1` on the `contentContainerStyle`, it causes the dimensions of the content to match (flex) to dimensions of the parent, removing the ability to scroll. `flexGrow: 1` will cause the content to fill empty space, but also allow the content to grow if it exceeds the screen's dimensions.

Comment: @MoistboboI guess here the only key is that flex: 1 has flexShrink: 1 in it, that's why flex: 1 doesn't work. doesn't it ?